# How can I have multiple states in my Store which are using the same reducer logic?

Tags: angular, angular5, ngrx, ngrx-store

Based on the `ngrx/store` example (https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md) I would like to have 2 independent states of a counter in my Store with the keys `count1` and `count2`. They are defined in the following code:

```
// counter.ts
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const INCREMENT = 'INCREMENT';

export function counterReducer(state: number = 0, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INCREMENT:
      return state + 1;

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// app-module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { counterReducer } from './counter';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ count1: counterReducer, count2: counterReducer })
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

What do I need to change to be able to dispatch 2 different increment actions (like `store.dispatch({ type: INCREMENT })`) to the store which update either `count1` or `count2` but not both of them? Am I missing something here or is this kind of behaviour not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have two separate actions for counter 1 and counter 2

Example

```
export const INCREMENT_COUNTER_1 = 'INCREMENT_COUNTER_1';
export const INCREMENT_COUNTER_2 = 'INCREMENT_COUNTER_2';
```

Same goes for the decrement. You need to have two separate decrement actions for each counter.

And if you want to combine actions, say, for example, you want to increment counter1 and 5 sec later you want to increment counter2, you can do that in your, effector. In your effector, you will have two effects, one for incrementing counter1 and with an observable that waits for 5sec and later invokes counter2, and another effector that increments counter2.

Here is a [GitHub](https://github.com/eskinderg/Angular-CLI) real-world project that uses RxJs 6 and angular 6. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Well you need to pass the current state to the function, as usually is done with Redux. So you need to pass the `state.count1` or `state.count2` depending on your business logic.

How this is exactly achieved in your application right now is depending on the rest of your code, but the `counterReducer` certainly seems able to take two versions of state. It's all about the spot where you manage the actual state.

In the ideal situation here, you would have a `state` object at some point that you ask things from for your application view, this is where you would store 2 versions of the `variable count` named `count1` and `count2` or whatever. You could even go as far as having only 1 `count` `object` that would contain 2 `subvariables`, but I'm assuming this is just for testing.

If you add more code to your example or setup a `stackblitz.com` link, we may be able to help you out a bit more.

Comment: the current state IS passed to the reducer function, as it's usually done with redux. It does not depend on the rest of my code, as the reducer is exaclty the spot where you manage state in redux. And no, I don't want to have a state containing 2 variables, this does not match my use case in the question as it's about REUSING reducer logic for the SAME state.